# .contains of jquery.. It doesn't work the way I want. Any other solution?

Tags: jquery

I'm supposed to find a value in a table using jquery. I used ".contains" but it doesn't work the way I want.

My Code:

```
var td=$('#table tr > td:first:contains(\"'+search+'\")').length;          
          if(td>0){
              $("#message").html('Already added in the list.');
          }
```

I think *".contains()"* search a value in td of table but not as certain as exact value. For an instance,  I'm trying to search 'ample' in a table. One value of td in the existing table is 
"example", it will return TRUE because 'ample' really exist in the word "example"...It works like a 'LIKE' query in sql.. What i want is to return TRUE if the value is exactly as it is...

Who ever got the idea that i was trying to say, any suggestion or alternative way/s aside from using .contains? A big Thank You for those who could give.

Comment: Do you need to check just the first `td` or each tr?

Comment: just the first td of each tr of the table..

Answer (score 0):

How about using `filter`? `filter` will help you to apply a filter condition on a set of items, and return the subset of items that matches the condition.

```
var td = $('#table tr > td:first').filter(function() { return $(this).html() == search;});
if(td.length)
   alert ('Already added in the list.'});
```

Here is demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qp51sgL6/1/

Comment: I've tried this one but still adding a value to the table even when the value is already added in the table :(

Comment: @NormanCabilatazan `when the value is already added ` means a table cell contains the value, right?

Comment: yeah...i've got one question..what does "td:first" mean?

Comment: `:first` brings the first `td` instance, so we need it actually, I got confused. check this: https://jsfiddle.net/qp51sgL6/1/

Comment: It works on you..but got a problem on mine..still adding even when the value is already existing in the table. maybe because on how i executed it...

Comment: @NormanCabilatazan that means you need to share your html output and more code

Comment: @NormanCabilatazan how do you execute it? you can share jsfiddle?

Comment: Already found the problem. I've got some issues regarding first and first-child.. And now it works...still A big thank you sir for your quick response. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using contains you could use this filter function.

```
var td=$('#table tr > td:first').filter(function() {return $(this).text() == search;}).length;
```

filter function is more powerful and you can have more control.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried this one but still adding a value to the table even when the value is already added in the table :(

Comment: Give me your html sample.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could use is to use a regex to match the text exactly as you want with word boundaries. It's easy enough to extend the selectors and write your own to do this with said regex, using the following as an example:

```
$.expr[":"].matches = function(obj, index, meta, stack){
    var regX = new RegExp('\\b'+meta[3]+'\\b');
    return regX.test(obj.textContent || obj.innerText || $(obj).text() || "");
}
```

Called like:

```
$('td:first:matches(\"'+search+'\")');
```

Or you can use the same regex in a filter to test against the .text() of the element.

This will work with single and multi-word sections. If you had three cells with "sample", "ample", and "solid example" and used

```
$('td:matches("ample")');
```

it would only return the one with "ample". Likewise, searching with "example" would still match "solid example" because the exact word exists in there.

If you want to match only the entire text, the other solutions matching .html() or .text() to the term passed will do a match of the entire content of the cell.